# android Ccavenue integration where do i find jsp files?

Tags: android, ccavenue

I am working with payment gateway integration for a first time. Currently am working with CCAvenue non-seemless android application implementation. I understand the concept but I didn't find two files inside my non-seemless kit that is cavResponseHandler.jsp and GetRSA.jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Those file exist in your android tab, top right corner of the page. You must keep those files into server side folder and place files path in your java file in android. Also put your RSA key before putting your GETRSA.jsp file at server.

Comment: will you please elaborate where is exactly the android tab . I got a Zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly follow the below steps for implementing the Payment Gateway on your Mobile Application by Non Seamless Method :

1. Kindly make sure that your Public/Outgoing IP has been whitlisted on CCAvenue's end.
2. Place GetRSA and ccavResponseHandler files on your server.
3. In your App, mention the path of GetRSA file kept on your server
4. Call GetRSA from your app which is kept on the your server for fetching the rsa public key.
5. Using the fetched public key merchant will encrypt parameters(amount,currency).
6. After encrypting the parameters you will post the encrypted value along with the other billing shipping details(if any) to the CCAvenue server via a browser(embedded webview) post.
7. The user will be redirected to the CCAvenue's billing shipping page where he will fill in the required details including the payment option.
8. After filling the required details he will be redirected to the bank page wherein he will authorize himself.
9. After authorization he will be redirected to CCAvenue and a response i.e. Success or failure will be sent to the merchant page which was configured as return url during registration.
10. You should then decrypt the response, which can then be parsed to get transaction status.   Note :

    - Access code and order ID should be the same as passed during the RSA call.
    - Order ID should always be unique
    - The transaction should hit the CCAvenue server within 60 seconds after receiving the RSA key.
    - Working key posted in ccavResponseHandler file should be corresponding to the Accesscode being posted to CCAvenue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all your keys and APIs from CCAvenue dashboard.
Go to CCAvenue.com for merchant login, use your credential- Username & password.

Now goto Implementation option and select RSA handling and RSAKey.